# How to remove trailing comments via regexp?

Tags: regex, string, matlab, parsing

For non-MATLAB-savvy readers: not sure what family they belong to, but the MATLAB regexes are described [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) in full detail. MATLAB's comment character is `%` (percent) and its string delimiter is `'` (apostrophe). A string delimiter inside a string is written as a double-apostophe (`'this is how you write "it''s" in a string.'`). To complicate matters more, the matrix transpose operators are *also* apostrophes (`A'` (Hermitian) or `A.'` (regular)).

Now, for dark reasons (that I will **not** elaborate on :), I'm trying to interpret MATLAB code in MATLAB's own language.

Currently I'm trying to remove all trailing comments in a cell-array of strings, each containing a line of MATLAB code. At first glance, this might seem simple:

```
>> str = 'simpleCommand(); % simple trailing comment';
>> regexprep(str, '%.*$', '')
ans =
    simpleCommand();
```

But of course, something like this might come along:

```
>> str = ' fprintf(''%d%*c%3.0f\n'', value, args{:}); % Let''s do this! ';
>> regexprep(str, '%.*$', '') 
ans = 
    fprintf('        %//   <-- WRONG!
```

Obviously, we need to exclude all comment characters that reside inside strings from the match, while also taking into account that a single apostrophe (or a dot-aposrotphe) directly following a statement is an *operator*, not a string delimiter.

Based on the assumption that the amount of string opening/closing characters *before* the comment character must be *even* (which I know is incomplete, because of the matrix-transpose operator), I conjured up the following dynamic regex to handle this sort of case:

```
>> str = {
       'myFun( {''test'' ''%''}); % let''s '                 
       'sprintf(str, ''%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n''); % it''s '        
       'sprintf(str, ''%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n''); % let''s '       
       'sprintf(str, ''%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n'');  '
       'A = A.'';%tight trailing comment'
   };
>> 
>> C = regexprep(str, '(^.*)(?@mod(sum(\1==''''''''),2)==0;)(%.*$)', '$1')
```

However,

```
C = 
    'myFun( {'test' '%'}); '              %// sucess
    'sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n'); '  %// sucess
    'sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n'); '  %// sucess
    'sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c'           %// FAIL
    'A = A.';'                            %// success (although I'm not sure why)
```

so I'm *almost* there, but not quite yet :)

Unfortunately I've exhausted the amount of time I can spend thinking about this and need to continue with other things, so perhaps someone else who has more time is friendly enough to think about these questions:

1. Are comment characters inside strings the *only* exception I need to look out for?
2. What is the correct and/or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I don't know matlab but how about using non greedy quantifier: `%.*?$`

Comment: @M42: well that seems to fix the issue, at least for my small subset of tests...Can you post as an answer?

Comment: @M42: no wait, I didn't look close enough -- it *doesn't* fix the issue...in fact, it doesn't do anything anymore :)

Comment: Well, if instructions end with semicolon, may be this will work: substitute `;\s*%.*?$` by `;`

Comment: @M42: unfortunately, not all lines end in semicolon (for example, `if (condition) % trailing comment` is a commonly occuring pattern)

Comment: Too bad, so I guess the best way is a parser.

Comment: Are you going to keep directives like `%#ok` and `%#codegen`, or it is OK to remove them as well?

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia: I'm only interested in the statements, so it's OK to remove them

Comment: Somehow I feel that it would be easier to write a finite state machine parser than to write its corresponding regex.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Probably you are right...I'm just exploring the possibility that I've overlooked something obvious (or not-so-obvious-and-easy-to-miss)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis if Matlab supports unbounded lookbehind, you can convert that FSM into a regex, and use that as the lookbehind. The starting and ending state for the lookbehind would be the "normal" context. The part after the lookbehind would be easy.

Comment: @JanDvorak: AFAIK, MATLAB indeed has support for this. It's then "just" a matter of finding the regex that finds: "the longest substring where everything before the comment character contains an even number of string enclosing characters, where the string enclosing characters are counted *only* if they are not directly attached to a non-space character that is not in a string itself."...sounds like fun :)

Comment: So, every apostrophe that is not directly after `A`, `A.` or commented out is a string delimiter?

Comment: How does matlab treat newlines inside strings?

Comment: @JanDvorak: indeed (of course, your '`A`' is any valid statement, and '`'`' and '`.'`' are the transpose operators). Newlines in strings are not supported directly (you'd construct a 2D array of strings to accomplish that, *or* use `char(10)` in a 1D array, *or* use `\n` in `fprintf()` and friends.)

Comment: umm... then I need the grammar for a valid statement, or at least a grammar disambiguating between the valid context for a matrix transposition and the valid context for a string literal. I don't know the syntax of Matlab, but I do understand the theory of parsing a specific grammar.

Comment: @JanDvorak: the details are of course a bit too long for a comment, but I think you'll find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it) useful. For the transposes: every apostrophe preceeded by a non-whitespace and non-apostrophe character, is a matrix transpose operator, provided it is not inside an apostrophe-delimited string.

Comment: @JanDvorak: An apostophe not preceeded by a string itself, and *directly* preceeded by `\s`, `\(`, `\[` or `\{`, is a string opening character. The next odd apostrphe, when not counting *double* apostrophes, is a string terminator (as you may notice, I'm having trouble even defining it :))

Comment: by "not preceeded by a string itself", do you mean that in `'hello' '`, the last `'` denotes a matrix transpose? What about `'hello' op 'world'`?

Comment: @JanDvorak: `'hello''` is not valid (directly preceeded by apostrophe), while `'hello'.'` is indeed a valid transpose of the character array. Something like `'hello'.^ 'world'` is a valid statement (`.^` is element-wise exponentiation, and a character array is (like C) just an array of numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This matches conjugate transpose case by checking what characters are allowed before one

1. Numbers  `2'`
2. Letters `A'`
3. Dot `A.'`
4. Left parenthesis, brace and bracket `A(1)'`, `A{1}'` and `[1 2 3]'`

These are the only cases I can think of now.

```
C = regexprep(str, '^(([^'']*''[^'']*''|[^'']*[\.a-zA-Z0-9\)\}\]]''[^'']*)*[^'']*)%.*$', '$1')
```

on your example we it returns

```
>> C = regexprep(str, '^(([^'']*''[^'']*''|[^'']*[\.a-zA-Z0-9\)\}\]]''[^'']*)*[^'']*)%.*$', '$1')

C = 

    'myFun( {'test' '%'}); '
    'sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n'); '
    'sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n'); '
    'sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n');  '
    'A = A.';'
```

Comment: +1 (again): starting to look good...further testing required though.

Comment: @M42 Your comment is superfluous since he's using `[^'']*`.

Comment: @M42 It's not the case. You see `[^'']` but it's not the actual string. Matlab will convert it to `[^']`. If you want to have an apostrophe in a MATLAB string you have to repeat it. If you run `disp('It''s a string')`, you get `It's a string`.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia: Ok, sorry, my bad. I don't know MATLAB syntax.

Comment: Look at my answer :) Can you see if you can find a construct on which it fails?

Comment: I'll still accept your answer, since also your solution has withstood my tests up to now, and your hacky efforts are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hmm...something that hasn't occurred to me yet: multi-line comments (`%{ ... %}`) should ideally *also* be removed (completely)...

Comment: Thanks for choosing this one. I think if you want to handle multi-lines you need to change your data structure. Cell array will cause more trouble. You need to bring it back to a long multi-line string.

Comment: Well, I'll treat multiline comments separately (pretty easy, although not in a one-liner AFAIK)...I think it's pretty much impossible to strip *also those* in a one-liner :)

Answer (score 5):

How do you feel about using undocumented features? If you dont object, you can use the `mtree` function to parse the code and strip the comments. No regexps involved, and [we all know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/97160) that we shouldn't try to parse context-free grammars using regular expressions.

This function is a full parser of MATLAB code written in pure M-code. As far as I can tell, it is an experimental implementation, but it's already used by Mathworks in a few places (this is the same function used by [MATLAB Cody](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34754-calculate-size) and [Contests](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/contest/contests/36/rules#Node%20Count) to measure code length), and can be used for [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16407557/97160) useful things.

If the input is a cellarray of strings, we do:

```
>> str = {..};
>> C = deblank(cellfun(@(s) tree2str(mtree(s)), str, 'UniformOutput',false))
C = 
    'myFun( { 'test', '%' } );'
    'sprintf( str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n' );'
    'sprintf( str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n' );'
    'sprintf( str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n' );'
    'A = A.';'
```

If you already have an M-file stored on disk, you can strip the comments simply as:

```
s = tree2str(mtree('myfile.m', '-file'))
```

If you want to see the comments back, add: `mtree(.., '-comments')`

Comment: to be exact `mtree` calls a builtin function `mtreemex`, so its not a pure M-code function

Answer (score 4):

Look what I found! :)

[The comment stripping toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4645-matlab-comment-stripping-toolbox/content/mlstripcomments/mlstripcommentsstr.m), by Peter J. Acklam.

For m-code, it contains the following regex:

```
mainregex = [ ...
     ' (                   ' ... % Grouping parenthesis (content goes to $1).
     '   ( ^ | \n )        ' ... % Beginning of string or beginning of line.
     '   (                 ' ... % Non-capturing grouping parenthesis.
     '                     ' ...
     '' ... % Match anything that is neither a comment nor a string...
     '       (             ' ... % Non-capturing grouping parenthesis.
     '           [\]\)}\w.]' ... % Either a character followed by
     '           ''+       ' ... %    one or more transpose operators
     '         |           ' ... % or else
     '           [^''%]    ' ... %   any character except single quote (which
     '                     ' ... %   starts a string) or a percent sign (which
     '                     ' ... %   starts a comment).
     '       )+            ' ... % Match one or more times.
     '                     ' ...
     '' ...  % ...or...
     '     |               ' ...
     '                     ' ...
     '' ...  % ...match a string.
     '       ''            ' ... % Opening single quote that starts the string.
     '         [^''\n]*    ' ... % Zero or more chars that are neither single
     '                     ' ... %   quotes (special) nor newlines (illegal).
     '         (           ' ... % Non-capturing grouping parenthesis.
     '           ''''      ' ... % An embedded (literal) single quote character.
     '           [^''\n]*  ' ... % Again, zero or more chars that are neither
     '                     ' ... %   single quotes nor newlines.
     '         )*          ' ... % Match zero or more times.
     '       ''            ' ... % Closing single quote that ends the string.
     '                     ' ...
     '   )*                ' ... % Match zero or more times.
     ' )                   ' ...
     ' [^\n]*              ' ... % What remains must be a comment.
              ];

  % Remove all the blanks from the regex.
  mainregex = mainregex(~isspace(mainregex));
```

Which becomes

```
mainregex  = '((^|\n)(([\]\)}\w.]''+|[^''%])+|''[^''\n]*(''''[^''\n]*)*'')*)[^\n]*'
```

and should be used as

```
C = regexprep(str, mainregex, '$1')
```

So far, it's withstood all of my tests, so I think this should solve my problem quite nicely :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to abuse [checkcode](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/checkcode.html) (the replacement for old [mlint](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/mlint.html)) to do the parsing. Here is a suggestion

```
function strNC = removeComments(str)
if iscell(str)
    strNC = cellfun(@removeComments, str, 'UniformOutput', false);
elseif regexp(str, '%', 'once')
    err = getCheckCodeId(str);
    strNC = regexprep(str, '%[^%]*$', '');
    errNC = getCheckCodeId(strNC);
    if strcmp(err, errNC),
        strNC = removeComments(strNC);
    else
        strNC = str;
    end
else
    strNC = str;
end
end

function errid = getCheckCodeId(line)
fName = 'someTempFileName.m';
fh = fopen(fName, 'w');
fprintf(fh, '%s\n', line);
fclose(fh);
if exist('checkcode')
    structRep = checkcode(fName, '-id');
else
    structRep = mlint(fName, '-id');
end
delete(fName);
if isempty(structRep)
    errid = '';
else
    errid = structRep.id;
end
end
```

For each line, it checks if we introduce an error by trimming the line from last `%` to the end of line.

For your example it returns:

```
>> removeComments(str)

ans = 

    'myFun( {'test' '%'}); '
    'sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n'); '
    'sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n'); '
    'sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n');  '
    'A = A.';'
```

It does not remove the suppression directive, `%#ok`, so you get:

```
>> removeComments('a=1; %#ok')

ans =

a=1; %#ok
```

Which probably is a good thing.

Comment: +1: you, my good sir, are quickly becoming my new hero! You're so full of dirty tricks :p Anyway, although I agree that this is probably the more robust and "better" way to go, it feels awfully verbose...plus, it creates a version dependency: I'm on R2010a, so I'll have to use `mlint` instead of `codecheck` (which, ideally, I'd have to check for). So I'll leave the question open for a while longer, see if a regex one-liner is *really* not possible.

Comment: Thansk for the kind words! Indeed not as succinct as a one-liner `regexprep`. I'm also curious about a solution with regex but I see many special cases to treat mostly due to the fact that `´` can be used both for string and conjugate transpose.

Comment: Yes, that apostrophe is a nasty one isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

How about making sure all apostrophe before the comment come in pairs like this:

```
>> str = {
       'myFun( {''test'' ''%''}); % let''s '                 
       'sprintf(str, ''%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n''); % it''s '        
       'sprintf(str, ''%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n''); % let''s '       
       'sprintf(str, ''%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n'');  '
   };

>> C = regexprep(str, '^(([^'']*''[^'']*'')*[^'']*)%.*$', '$1')

C = 
    myFun( {'test' '%'}); 
    sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n'); 
    sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n'); 
    sprintf(str, '%*8.0f%*s%c%3d\n');
```

Comment: looks better...but unfortunately fails on something like `str = 'A = A.'';%trailing comment'`