# Find comments using %, ingore printf with %d using regex

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm trying to pull out comments in a MATLAB file. In MATLAB, comments are denoted with % so the sensible thing would be to search for `%.*`. However, MATLAB also has functions like sprintf and fprintf which allow something like `sprintf('x = %d', 5)` and that regex would find `%d', 5)` as well, which I don't want. Of course I'd also want to ignore variations such as `%s` or `%f`. Is there a way to capture only those segments that match `%.*` but which are not enclosed in `'` characters? I suppose I should clarify that I'm generally trying to capture comments starting with `%`, but ignoring any `%` within string literals. The sprintf was simply an example of such an occurence that I want to ignore.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359425/how-to-remove-trailing-comments-via-regexp), which seems related, but no solutions posted there solve my problem.

Comment: If you assume that all 'real' comments have a leading space, `%\s.*` might work.

Comment: That is generally the case, but might not be always. I'd prefer something that captured the cases where someone commented without a space.

Comment: If you're confident with vim then this answer might help [Match by syntax highlighting instead of expressions](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3573/4655)

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately, given my constraints, I cannot use plugins. Nice find though!

Comment: Another idea: if you use the MATLAB editor to publish it produces an HTML version of the script and puts all comments in a `<span class="comment"></span>` element. Maybe these would be easier to remove. Pretty convoluted and not particularly automated, but if it's just for a few big files it might work.

Comment: In addition, there's the matlab function [`publish`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html).

Answer (score 2):

My final regex :

> - **`^(^[^']+|[^']+('.*')+[^']+)?(;|,)\s*%(?<com>.*)|^(\s)*%(?<com2>.*)`**

```
regexp('%i am a comment', '^(^[^'']+|[^'']+(''.*'')+[^'']+)?(;|,)\s*%(?<com>.*)|^(\s)*%(?<com2>.*)', 'names')
```

response:

```
com2: 'i am a comment'
com: []
```

---

```
 regexp('printf () ; %i am a comment after a command','^(^[^'']+|[^'']+(''.*'')+[^'']+)?(;|,)\s*%(?<com>.*)|^(\s)*%(?<com2>.*)', 'names')
```

response:

```
 com2: []
 com: 'i am a comment after a command'
```

---

```
  regexp('printf ('' % i m not a comment '') , %i am a comment after a command followed by comma', '^(^[^'']+|[^'']+(''.*'')+[^'']+)?(;|,)\s*%(?<com>.*)|^(\s)*%(?<com2>.*)', 'names')
```

Response:

```
com2: []
 com: 'i am a comment after a command followed by comma'
```

---

This case to make sure the comment isnt caught:

```
regexp('printf('' ;%i m not a comment '');', '^(^[^'']+|[^'']+(''.*'')+[^'']+)?(;|,)\s*%(?<com>.*)|^(\s)*%(?<com2>.*)', 'names')
```

ans =

```
0x0 struct array with fields:
com2
com
```

the comments are stored in variables `com` and  `com2`

Comment: That is similar to something I had tried, but doesn't do fully what I want. First, it picks up any trailing `;` in the line, and second, it doesn't catch any comment after a line not ending in `;`.

Comment: @zephyr do you mean a line ending with `,` ? its simple, just add it aside !

Comment: No, ending in `;`. You have `;(\s)*%.*)` in that which, from the line `sprintf('%d',5); %comment` would find `; %comment`. What's more, it wouldn't find the comment in `if (true) %this is true`.

Comment: @zephyr get rid of first character using `string(2:end)` lol whats more ?

Comment: @zephyr  the tokens are stored in `com` and `com2`

Comment: Sorry to be so particular, but I cannot use the group structure `(?`.

Comment: @zephyr use 'names' instead of 'match'

Comment: @zephyr happy satisfied now !! :D

Comment: As I said, I cannot use the `(?` group structure. With the regex available to me, that is not a valid option. Thanks for all the effort you put in though. Hopefully it will help someone else who may have a similar issue.

Comment: That is not an option for me. What's more, I'm only using regex on matlab files, not regex from matlab.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't meet the question's requirements, but I thought I'd share it anyway.

If MATLAB is accessible, then you can use the [`publish`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html) function, then pull out the comments with `grep`.

So for the following function in `myfun.m`

```
function [out] = myfun(n) 
% Comment
out = ['% Not a ',... this is a comment too
    'comment'];
fprintf('%d',n)%do this
%{
 Multiline
 comment
%}
```

we run

```
publish('myfun.m')
```

which produces the file `html/myfun.html`. Now with e.g. bash, we can run

```
egrep -o -e "<span class=\"comment\">.*?</span>" html/myfun.html
```

which returns

```
<span class="comment">% Comment</span>
<span class="comment"> this is a comment too</span>
<span class="comment">%do this</span>
<span class="comment">%}</span>
```

This is not quite there, since `publish` has split lines like this

```
<span class="comment">%{
</span><span class="comment"> Multiline
</span><span class="comment"> comment, n&gt;2
</span><span class="comment">%}</span>
```

This needs [How can I search for a multiline pattern in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file)