# How to tell if Matlab code is syntactically valid?

Tags: matlab, parsing

I'm working on a parser for Matlab, using a whole bunch of code from the Matlab Central File Exchange as test data. While sifting through some of it, I found that some of the code I downloaded legitimately shouldn't parse (i.e. Matlab itself won't accept it).

Is there an easy way to check if an m-file (either function or script) contains syntax errors -- perhaps some library function? I'm not looking to run the code, just see if it should parse.

Comment: lookup CHECKCODE/MLINT or the undocumented MTREE functions

Comment: It sounds interesting.. Out of curiosity, is your project publicly accessible?

Comment: @Amro it's part of the McLab project at McGill university (http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/mclab/, https://github.com/Sable/mclab). I thought it simpler to say "I'm working on a parser" but that's not quite true :s

Comment: very nice! Here is a look at how many submissions are using these parsing functions: http://mcbench.cs.mcgill.ca/list?query=%2F%2FParameterizedExpr[is_call%28%27mtree%27%29+or+is_call%28%27mlint%27%29+or+is_call%28%27checkcode%27%29]&query_id=12

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are willing to use undocumented functions, consider the following:

```
function isValid = checkValidMFile(file_name)
    % make sure file can be found
    fname = which(file_name);
    assert(~isempty(fname) && exist(fname,'file')~=0, 'file not found');

    % parse M-file and validate
    t = mtree(fname, '-file');
    if count(t) == 0 || (count(t)==1 && iskind(t,'ERR'))
        isValid = false;
    else
        isValid = true;
    end
end
```

(You could also pass it a string of MATLAB language code instead of a saved file name).

Of course `mtree` will give a lot more information, it can actually return the parse tree, as well as any warnings or errors. I have previously used it to [differentiate between scripts vs. functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16407557), and to [strip all comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17370134) from an M-file.

It is unfortunately not officially supported, so you will have to browse its source code to figure out what everything means (thankfully it is well commented). The function uses the internal `mtreemex` MEX-function.

---

Additional (undocumented) ways:

```
builtin('_mcheck', 'some_file.m')
```

and

```
checkSyntacticWarnings('./path/to/folder/')
```

Comment: This seems close to what I want, but it doesn't seem to catch all syntax errors. For instance, Matlab gives an error for `[1,,2]`, but `mtree('[1,,2]')` doesn't. I guess Matlab catches that error after the parsing stage for some reason?

Comment: huh you are right! Actually it seems to correct it :) `tree2str(mtree('[1,,2]'))` returns `[1,2]`. Try my other suggested solutions..

Answer (score 4):

Since 2011b the way to parse Matlab code is via [`checkcode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/checkcode.html). In older versions of Matlab you can use [`mlint`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mlint.html) (in R2013a+, and maybe earlier, this command just calls `checkcode`). Both of these rely on a private undocumented function called `mlintmex`. You can learn a bit more about this function and related topics [on the Undocumented Matlab website](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/parsing-mlint-code-analyzer-output/).

Another potentially-related project is [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist), which is used by GitHub and others to classify languages and uses [pygments.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/pygments.rb) to highlight code. It supports Matlab. A while back the Matlab support used to be hit-or-miss, but I think that it has improved. These won't validate code, but they may be useful for what you're doing.

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish syntax errors from other problems? I have the same problem here as with the other answer; e.g. `[1,,2]` gets a warning like `a comma cannot immediately follow another comma`, while others get something with `parse error` which is easy to look for.